# Is every integer representable as the sum of four Fibonacci squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

**Lagrange's Four Square Theorem.** Every positive integer $N$ can be written as the sum of four squares, i.e.,

$$N = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2.$$

**Zeckendorf's Theorem.** Every integer has a unique representation where it can be written as the sum of non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers. i.e.,

$$N = \sum_i F_{c_i}, c_i \in \mathbb{Z}, c_i \ge 2, c_{i+1} \gt c_i + 1,$$

where $F_k$ is the Fibonacci sequence generated by the recurrence equation $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n$ with $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$.

**Question:** Is every positive integer also representable as the sum of four Fibonacci squares?

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= F_0^2 \\
1 &= F_1^2 \\
2 &= F_1^2 + F_1^2 \\
3 &= F_1^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 \\
4 &= F_3^2 \\
5 &= F_3^2 + F_1^2 \\
6 &= F_3^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 \\
7 &= F_3^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 \\
8 &= F_3^2 + F_3^2 \\
9 &= F_4^2 \\
10 &= F_4^2 + F_1^2 \\
11 &= F_4^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 \\
12 &= F_4^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 \\
13 &= F_4^2 + F_3^2 \\
14 &= F_4^2 + F_3^2 + F_1^2 \\
15 &= F_4^2 + F_3^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 \\
16 &= F_3^2 + F_3^2 + F_3^2 + F_3^2
\end{align}
$$

Note that in the sums above, if we have fewer than $4$ squares, we can always add $F_0^2 = 0^2$ to make it a four square representation.

The sum of four Fibonacci squares representation, if it exists, is not necessarily unique for an integer. e.g.,

$$
\begin{align}
4 &= F_1^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 + F_1^2 \\
  &= F_3^2 + F_0^2 + F_0^2 + F_0^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Bruteforce gives that first gap is $24$: the only Fibonacci squares less than $24$ are $0, 1, 4, 9$. We need at least two nines (otherwise sum is at most $9 + 3 \cdot 4 = 21$), so now we have to represent $6$ as sum of two numbers from $0,1,4$. But such sum is either $8$, or at most $5$. Thus $24$ isn't sum of $4$ Fibonacci squares.

It is not hard to find representation for numbers from 17 to 23.

(but of course Empy2's argument is much more elegant then this)

Comment: Your answer is better (more elegant) I think. Finding such a small counter example is a more convincing proof than using function growth rate (for example, the other might need some more proof to show ln^4 N grows more slowly than N to be completely rigorous, while yours is already complete).

Comment: This shows the two types of proofs: One is fast and rigorous, but doesn't betray much insight; another is slow and perhaps verbose/unclear, but has much more to learn from.

Comment: @justhalf: on the other hand, it is straightforward to see how Empy2's answer could be extended to the more general question "does there exist a $k$ such that every positive integer can be expressed by $k$ Fibonacci squares"

Answer (score 80):

If $N$ is big, there are only about $\ln N$ Fibonacci squares below $N$.  There are then at most $(\ln N)^4$ different sums below $N$.  That count eventually grows more slowly than $N$, so gaps will appear.
I don't know when the first gap will be

Comment: Thank you. I've accepted @mihaild's answer and upvoted yours. Your explanation is concise and logical.

Comment: It follows from this that for every $k$, there are integers that are not representable as a sum of $k$ Fibonacci squares.

Comment: And more general, for any non-periodic linear recurrent sequence, any set of $n$ functions that grow at least linearly, and number $k$, there are numbers that are not sum of at most $k$ terms where each term is function of some term of sequence.

Answer (score 17):

By computer search, the possible representations for integers up to 50 are (note, $F_2=1=F_1$ so we only give representations using $F_1$ for brevity)
\begin{align}
0 &= F_0^2&
1 &= F_{1}^2\\
2 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2&
3 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2\\
4 &= F_{3}^2&
4 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2\\
5 &= F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2&
6 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2\\
7 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2&
8 &= F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2\\
9 &= F_{4}^2&
9 &= F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2\\
10 &= F_{1}^2+F_{4}^2&
10 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2\\
11 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{4}^2&
12 &= F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2\\
12 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{4}^2&
13 &= F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2\\
13 &= F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2&
14 &= F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2\\
15 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2&
16 &= F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2\\
17 &= F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2&
18 &= F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2\\
18 &= F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2&
19 &= F_{1}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2\\
20 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2&
21 &= F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2\\
22 &= F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2&
23 &= F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2\\
25 &= F_{5}^2&
26 &= F_{1}^2+F_{5}^2\\
26 &= F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2&
27 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{5}^2\\
27 &= F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2&
28 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{5}^2\\
28 &= F_{1}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2&
29 &= F_{3}^2+F_{5}^2\\
30 &= F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{5}^2&
31 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{5}^2\\
31 &= F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2&
33 &= F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{5}^2\\
34 &= F_{4}^2+F_{5}^2&
34 &= F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{5}^2\\
35 &= F_{1}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{5}^2&
36 &= F_{1}^2+F_{1}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{5}^2\\
36 &= F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2&
37 &= F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{5}^2\\
38 &= F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{5}^2&
39 &= F_{1}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{5}^2\\
42 &= F_{3}^2+F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{5}^2&
43 &= F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{5}^2\\
44 &= F_{1}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{5}^2&
47 &= F_{3}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{4}^2+F_{5}^2\\
50 &= F_{5}^2+F_{5}^2.&
\end{align}

The integers up to $1000$ without such a representation are

```
24, 32, 40, 41, 45, 46, 48, 49, 53, 56, 57, 61, 62, 71, 80, 85, 87, 88, 92, 95, 96, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 116, 117, 119, 120, 121, 122, 124, 125, 126, 127, 131, 134, 135, 140, 142, 143, 144, 145, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 155, 156, 158, 159, 160, 161, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 176, 184, 185, 189, 190, 197, 200, 205, 206, 208, 209, 210, 211, 213, 214, 215, 216, 218, 221, 222, 224, 225, 226, 227, 229, 230, 231, 232, 236, 239, 240, 245, 247, 248, 249, 250, 252, 253, 254, 255, 257, 260, 261, 263, 264, 265, 266, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 299, 300, 302, 303, 304, 305, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 341, 344, 345, 349, 350, 352, 353, 354, 355, 357, 358, 359, 360, 362, 365, 366, 368, 369, 370, 371, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 404, 405, 407, 408, 409, 410, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 448, 456, 457, 461, 462, 464, 465, 469, 472, 473, 477, 478, 480, 481, 482, 483, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 493, 494, 496, 497, 498, 499, 501, 502, 503, 504, 512, 517, 519, 520, 521, 522, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 533, 535, 536, 537, 538, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 572, 574, 575, 576, 577, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 613, 616, 617, 621, 622, 624, 625, 626, 627, 629, 630, 631, 632, 634, 637, 638, 640, 641, 642, 643, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 673, 677, 679, 680, 681, 682, 684, 685, 686,687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 769, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777, 778, 781, 782, 784, 785, 786, 787, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802, 803, 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817, 818, 819, 820, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 885, 888, 889, 893, 894, 896, 897, 898, 899, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 909, 910, 912, 913, 914, 915, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 930, 931, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940, 941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 949, 951, 952, 953, 954, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999, 1000
```

The list of integers up to $1000$ with this representation is shorter:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 42, 43, 44, 47, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 58, 59, 60, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 89, 90, 91, 93, 94, 97, 98, 99, 100, 102, 107, 114, 115, 118, 123, 128, 129, 130, 132, 133, 136, 137, 138, 139, 141, 146, 153, 154, 157, 162, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 186, 187, 188, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 198, 199, 201, 202, 203, 204, 207, 212, 217, 219, 220, 223, 228, 233, 234, 235, 237, 238, 241, 242, 243, 244, 246, 251, 256, 258, 259, 262, 267, 283, 297, 298, 301, 306, 322, 338, 339, 340, 342, 343, 346, 347, 348, 351, 356, 361, 363, 364, 367, 372, 388, 402, 403, 406, 411, 427, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 458, 459, 460, 463, 466, 467, 468, 470, 471, 474, 475, 476, 479, 484, 491, 492, 495, 500, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 513, 514, 515, 516, 518, 523, 530, 531, 532, 534, 539, 555, 569, 570, 571, 573, 578, 594, 610, 611, 612, 614, 615, 618, 619, 620, 623, 628, 633, 635, 636, 639, 644, 660, 674, 675, 676, 678, 683, 699, 738, 779, 780, 783, 788, 804, 843, 882, 883, 884, 886, 887, 890, 891, 892, 895, 900, 907, 908, 911, 916, 932, 946, 947, 948, 950, 955, 971
```

This was created by the Scala 3 code below that can probably be improved; it runs in under a second on my computer if you set `max = 10000`. [Click here to run it online in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/clvnkhr/GizAs876TAiuni7Tq5Sftg/1).

```
val max = 1000

def fibFrom(n: Int, m: Int): LazyList[Int] =
  n #:: m #:: fibFrom(n + m, n + 2 * m)
val fib = fibFrom(0, 1)

def computeReprs(min: Int, max: Int) = (for
  n <- min to max
  f1 <- fib.takeWhile(f => f * f <= n)
  f2 <- fib.dropWhile(_ < f1).takeWhile(f => f * f <= n - f1 * f1)
  f3 <- fib.dropWhile(_ < f2).takeWhile(f => f * f <= n - f1 * f1 - f2 * f2)
  f4 <- fib
    .dropWhile(_ < f3)
    .takeWhile(f => f * f <= n - f1 * f1 - f2 * f2 - f3 * f3)
  if n == f1 * f1 + f2 * f2 + f3 * f3 + f4 * f4
yield (n +: Seq(f1, f2, f3, f4).map(fib.indexOf(_)))).distinct

val reprs = computeReprs(0, max)

def printForMathSE() =
  def formatRepr(r: Seq[Int]): String =
    if r(0) == 0 then "0 &= F_0^2"
    else
      s"${r(0)} &= " + r.tail
        .filter(_ != 0)
        .map(i => "F_{" + s"$i" + "}^2")
        .mkString("+")

  var counter = 0
  val endMarkerSeq = Seq("\\\\\n", "&  ")
  def endMarker = { counter += 1; endMarkerSeq(counter % 2) }

  extension (reprs: IndexedSeq[String])
    def myMkString(endMarker: => String, acc: Seq[String] = Seq()): String =
      reprs match
        case IndexedSeq()     => acc.mkString
        case IndexedSeq(repr) => (acc :+ repr).mkString
        case IndexedSeq(repr, _*) =>
          reprs.tail.myMkString(endMarker, acc :+ repr :+ endMarker)

  println("\\begin{align}")
  println(reprs.takeWhile(_(0) <= 50).map(formatRepr).myMkString(endMarker))
  println("\\end{align}")

  val partition = (0 to max).partition(k => reprs.exists(r => r(0) == k))
  println(s"integers with repr:${partition(0).mkString(", ")}")
  println(s"integers without repr:${partition(1).mkString(", ")}")
end printForMathSE

printForMathSE()
```

Comment: Those would both probably be good additions to OEIS

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to optimise the code to compute at least a few more thousand and then see if the OEIS wants it @Burnsba

Comment: @Calvin You can take a look at my answer where the first 12 553 integers are linked.

Comment: @infinitezero Well that's certainly more than mine :) I will add your code to the OEIS proposal?

Comment: @Calvin please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 7):

I've written the bruteforce approach in Mathematica and get results up to 10^9 in a matter of seconds on my machine. I get 12 553 distinct integers, in the range from $0$ to $1254718084=4 F_{22}^2$. I did however exclude F_0 = 0 from it, because it seemed pointless.

Here's a log plot, where the x-axis shows the n'th integer and the y-axis its value.

[image]

```
fibonacci = Table[Fibonacci[n]^2, {n, 1, 22}];
reverseFib[n_] := 
 SubsuperscriptBox["F", Position[fibonacci, n][[1, 1]] - 1, 2] // 
  DisplayForm
subsets = 
  Tuples[fibonacci, 1]~Join~Tuples[fibonacci, 2]~Join~
   Tuples[fibonacci, 3]~Join~Tuples[fibonacci, 4];
DeleteDuplicates[
  SortBy[{Total[#], Total[reverseFib /@ #]} & /@ subsets, 
   First]] // TableForm
```

Since the list is way too exhaustive, I uploaded it to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1eQMFupr)