# Is every positive integer representable as $N = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + dw^2, 1 \le d \le 7$ with $x,y,z,w$ as Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

This question is related to this [other MSE Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4738778) in which it was shown that every integer cannot be represented as the sum of four Fibonacci squares and the first exception is $24$.

There is a theorem that states that every positive integer can be represented in the form

$$N = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + dw^2, 1 \le d \le 7 \tag{1}$$

**Question:**

1. Is every positive integer representable in the form given in Eqn. (1) where $w, x, y, z$ are Fibonacci numbers?

   For example: $24 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 2\cdot3^2$
2. If the given range $1 \le d \le 7$ is not possible, how wide should it be?

---

One approach is to use the fact that $u \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a Fibonacci number iff $\exists v \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $5u^2 + 4 = v^2 \lor 5u^2 - 4 = v^2$.

So, $5|v^2 - 4$ or $5|v^2 + 4$ is necessary for $u^2$ to be a Fibonacci square.

How do we proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[n]$ be the set $\{0,1,...,n\}$ and given a set $X$ of natural numbers, define

$$F_7(X) =\{x^2+y^2+z^2+dw^2| w,x,y,z\in X, d\in[7]\} $$

The first question is, what is the cardinality of $F_7(X)$, if the cardinality of $X$ is $n$?

There isn't a way to determine exactly without knowing more about $X$, but we know that it must be less than $n^4\times 7$, simply by a  combinatorial argument.

If we take say the set of the first 20 Fibonacci numbers, lets denote it by  $\mathcal{f}_{20}$ then the largest element in $F_7(\mathcal{f}_{20})$ is of course the number created by choosing $x,y,z,w$ as the $20$th Fibonacci number, and $d=7$, the $20th$ Fibonacci number is $6765$, so the largest element in $F_7(\mathcal{f}_{20})$ is $10\times 6765^2 $, which is almost half a billion. We need to remember that we can also take larger Fibonacci numbers than the $20$th one, if we let the others be $1$ for example, so the cardinality of $F_7(f_{20})$ isn't the relavant Cardinality, rather we should ask how many Fibonacci numbers can we include before even one of them squared is too big, and just as an example, the $50$th Fibonacci number is ridiculously big, so we can safely consider the Cardinality of $F_7(\mathcal{f_{50}})$, which is still well below half a billion, so there is no way to create a bijection between $F_7(\mathcal{f_{50}})$ and $[10\times 6765^2]$, so somewhere in there is some number that can't be expressed in this way.

You can repeat this argument if you increase the range of $d$ but I don't think you'll ever find a large enough finite range to ever satisfy even the cardinality requirements, the Fibonacci numbers are just too sparse when you square them

Comment: What is the relationship between cardinality and largest element ?

Comment: If the largest element that can be made with 20 Fibonacci numbers in this way is bigger than the number of possible combinations of Fibonacci numbers in that specific way that could result in a number less than the largest number, then there must be some number less than that largest number that can't be expressed in this way